# Calculate $1+2+\ldots+(i-1)+(i-1)+(i+1)+(i+2)+\ldots+(j-1)+(j-1)+(j+1)+(j+2)+\ldots+n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}, i<j<n$ calculate:

$$1+2+\ldots+(i-1)+(i-1)+(i+1)+(i+2)+\ldots+(j-1)+(j-1)+(j+1)+(j+2)+\ldots+n $$

how many terms are there here I think we should do the sum of the first $n-2$ terms?

Comment: What is the pattern? If you're replacing $i$ with $i - 1$ and $j$ with $j - 1$, the sum is just $(1 + \ldots + n) - i + (i - 1) - j + (j - 1) = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2} - 2$. Otherwise, edit your question and give more details.

Comment: @GarethMa What more details do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^nk = 1+ \cdots + (i-1)+i+(i+1)+\cdots+(j-1)+j+(j+1)+\cdots +n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{equation*}

You ask us to calculate:

\begin{equation*}
1 + \cdots + (i-1) + (i-1) + (i+1) + \cdots + (j-1)+(j-1)+ (j+1) + \cdots + n
\end{equation*}

This is precisely $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-2$.

Answer (score 0):

That's trivial. You have a Gaussian sum minus two units. It's just a matter of interpreting and rewriting the terms. Note that

\begin{align}
&1 + \cdots + (i-1) + (\color{red}{i}-\color{red}{1}) + (i+1) + \cdots + (j-1)+(\color{blue}{j}-\color{blue}{1})+ (j+1) + \cdots + n\\
&= \left[1 + \cdots + (i-1) + \color{red}{i} + (i+1) + \cdots + (j-1)+\color{blue}{j}+ (j+1) + \cdots + n\right] -\color{red}{1}-\color{blue}{1}\\
&= \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]-2
\end{align}